# Start More than one Android Emulator at a time

Tags: android, android-emulator

After I updated my ADT/Tools to 20, I am not able to start Two Emulators at a time.

It worked Once. But i don't remember what i did that time.

I tried restart my system several times.

I don't know how to locate whats the problem in emulator.

the emulator is shown in TaskManager Process but not on screen.

**EDITED**:

Reported as bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34221&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: you are not able to "start" multiple emulators from your android virtual device manager??

Comment: @Sunny yes from Android Virtual Device Manager and also from Command Line. The Emualtor are started but not shown on screen.

Comment: Yes, I have to agree with your reported problem, I can't start more than one either - and it DID used to work. It's actually worse than you reported too. If you start emulator type 1, then try to start type 2 (nothing happens), kill emulator type 1 and try to start emulator type 3, then the 'queued up' type 2 emulator starts.

Comment: It's already been reported as a bug it seems:http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34221&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this bug is fixed in the latest version of SDK Tools, Revision 20.0.1.

From the [revision history](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html):

> Fixed problems with running more than one emulator and running
>   multiple emulators with GPU acceleration.

Comment: I am unable to see the new SDK Tools 20.0.1 updates in SDK Manager

Comment: I just updated yesterday using the SDK Manager. You can try downloading it manually from dl-ssl.google.com. There are answers on SO on how to do that.

Comment: I have downloaded SDK Tools 20.0.1 and the problem solved. But still it is not available in SDK Manager. Thanks for giving idea of downloading manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different AVD Manager for running more than one emulator.

Comment: There is only one AVD Manager. Do you mean to say that Start Emulator with different instance of AVD Manager. Then i did that but not working. Also tried Command line.